# Проблема при добавлении Framework сборок в SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, assembly, sqlclr

Есть необходимость добавления CLR сборки в связке с самописной библиотекой классов (подключение к внешнему веб-сервису). При установке библиотеки классов появляется ошибка, что необходимо добавить зависимые сборки.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [system.Xaml]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c5619 
34e089\system.XAml.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [system.servicemodel.internals]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [smdiagnostics]   
FROM 'D:\Assembly\smdiagnostics.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime.Serialization]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO


CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime.DurableInstancing]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Web.ApplicationServices]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.IdentityModel]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.DirectoryServices]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO


CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Drawing]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.EnterpriseServices]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO


CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Web]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime.Remoting]   
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

Проблема появляется когда пытаюсь добавить System.EnterpriseServices. Эта сборка ссылается на [System.Runtime.Remoting]. При ее установке - ошибка. Нужна сборка System.Web. Ставлю ее - ссылается что надо сначала поставить System.EnterpriseServices. Получается замкнутый круг. Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался? Что можно сделать?